# SQL - Allowing a user

Tags: sql, tweets

We're creating a twitter-like database using SQL. I'm having trouble creating a stored procedure for:

Allowing a user to retrieve top-2 most frequently used hash tags in his/her tweets.

UPDATE: This is my stored procedure

```
create or replace 
procedure TOP_2_FREQUENT_HASHTAGS is
first_hashtag varchar2(255);
second_hashtag varchar2(255);

begin

with TopTwoHashtags 
AS (
SELECT 
  t.userID,
  th.HASHTAGID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY COUNT(th.TWEETID) DESC) r

FROM 
  Tweet_Hashtag th
  INNER JOIN Tweets t
  ON th.TWEETID = t.TWEETID
WHERE 
  userID = t.userid
GROUP BY
  t.userID,
  th.HASHTAGID
)
SELECT 
  ht.TOPIC
 into first_hashtag
FROM
  Hashtag ht
  INNER JOIN TopTwoHashtags tt
  ON ht.HASHTAGID = tt.HASHTAGID
WHERE
  r < 3;

 dbms_output.put_line('Top 2 most frequent hashtags: '|| first_hashtag);

 exception 
  when no_data_found then
  dbms_output.put_line('This user does not exist');
  return;

end;
```

We have the following tables:

- Admin
- Follow
- Hashtag

  - HASHTAGID
  - TOPIC
- Tweet_Hashtag

  - TWEETHASHID
  - TWEETID
  - HASHTAGID
- Tweets

  - TWEETID
  - USERID
  - TWEETDATE
  - TWEETTIME
  - TWEETTEXT
- TwitUser

This is our stored procedure for searching for tweets:

```
create or replace 
procedure search_tweets(ttwitext in tweets.tweettext%type, tuserID in tweets.userid%type )
is
  twit_user  tweets.userid%type;
  twit_id tweets.tweetid%type;
  twit_text tweets.tweettext%type;

begin

  select tweettext into twit_text from tweets where userid = tuserid and tweettext like '%' ||ttwitext || '%';
  if twit_text is not null then

  dbms_output.put_line(twit_text);

 end if; 


exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('kersplat' );
    return;

end;
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any evident logic here to rank hashtags by frequency.  What have you tried?

Comment: I want someone to point me in the right direction for starting this. The above code only searches for tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would write it. Using a `WITH` block I would calculate the `ROW_NUMBER` Over the counts using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Note: this does not deal well with ties and will pull back arbitrary rows when they occur. You could use `RANK` if you want to show more than two hashtags in this case

```
with TopTwoHashtags
AS (

SELECT 
  t.userID,
  th.HASHTAGID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY COUNT(th.TWEETID) DESC) r
FROM 
  Tweet_Hashtag th
  INNER JOIN Tweets t
  ON th.TWEETID = t.TWEETID
WHERE 
  userID = 3
GROUP BY
  t.userID,
  th.HASHTAGID
)
SELECT
  ht.TOPIC
FROM
  Hashtag ht
  INNER JOIN TopTwoHashtags tt
  ON ht.HASHTAGID = tt.HASHTAGID
WHERE
  r < 3;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12123/2)

Comment: it says "no rows selected" on my sql developer

Comment: also I need this in a stored procedure or a function

Comment: `WHERE  userID = 3` may be causing you problems if you don't have a user id like that. Or if that user never used hashtags. I imagine you'll want `userID = tuserID` assuming that you create a parameter similar to the stored proc in your question. Also given what you have in your question you should be able to create your own stored proc or function.

Comment: It was working fine outside a stored procedure. When I put it in the stored procedure I get "ORA-06512: at line 1
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" If you still care to look I updated it at the top.

Comment: @FlyToHeaven you'll need to use a cursor. [Here's an example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#BABCFDJE). Of course you'll probably want to add in something like `if first_hashtag is null THEN first_hastag = v_Hashtag; ELSE second_hastag = v_Hashtag; END IF`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can get the most frequent hashtags using SQL such as this:

```
select tagid, COUNT(*) as cnt
from tweet_hashtag ht
where userid = tuserid
group by userid, tagid
order by cnt desc
limit 2
```

If you want the actual tag, you'd need to join in the tag name from the hashtag table.

If the `tweet_hashtag` table doesn't have the `userid`, then you might need to join in the `tweets` table:

```
select ht.tagid, COUNT(*) as cnt
from tweet_hashtag ht join
     tweets t
     on ht.tweetId = t.tweetId
where ht.userid = tuserid
group by t.userid, ht.tagId
order by cnt desc
limit 2
```

If you are using Oracle, replace the `limit 2` with 'rownum <= 2'.  If you are using SQL Server or Sybase, replace it with `top 2` in the `select` clause.

Conrad is absolutely right.  The correct format for `rownum` is:

select t.*
   from (select ht.tagid, COUNT(*) as cnt
         from tweet_hashtag ht join
              tweets t
              on ht.tweetId = t.tweetId
         where ht.userid = tuserid
         group by t.userid, ht.tagId
         order by cnt desc
        ) t
    where rownum <= 2

Comment: I need the most frequent not most recent. I've updated the tables to show their contents.

Comment: @FlyToHeaven . . . This is the most frequent.  That is what the `order by cnt desc` is doing.

Comment: It's giving me an error that it's not ended properly even after I edited everything and added a ;

Comment: @FlyToHeaven that's because `limit 2` is MySQL syntax and it doesn't work on Oracle

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer. I think this will work:  WHERE rownum <= <<upper limit>>) a
 WHERE b_rownum >= <<lower limit>>

Comment: @FlyToHeaven hmm rownum can be weird. I can't remember if it applies before or after the group by. You might have to use the WITH clause or an inline view and then limit with rownum. You could also use `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @GordonLinoff You definitely have to have to add an inline view or with caluse if you're going to use rownum. Compare the two results [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac771/2)

Comment: Guys, I need the topic not the hashtagid. I think I can transform the resulting id into the topic name.